# In Chrome settings, which style is used to achieve the box shadow for boxes?

Tags: css, google-chrome

In Chrome settings, which styles are used to achive the box shadow for boxes?

E.g.:

[image]

Comment: The `box-shadow` property.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is either a request for an off-site resource or a typo or problem so narrow as to help no one else but the asker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the settings page in much the same way you can inspect any other web page, as they are implemented with HTML and CSS and rendered just like a web page.

Sections of settings are implemented with a component that looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="settings-section" assetpath="settings_page/" css-build="shadow">
  <template>
    <style scope="settings-section">/* Styles omitted for brevity */
</style>
    <div id="header">
      <h2 class="title" aria-hidden$="[[getTitleHiddenStatus_(pageTitle)]]">[[pageTitle]]</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="card">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </template>
  </dom-module>
```

That scoped `style` element contains this CSS rule:

```css
#card {
  box-shadow: var(--cr-card-elevation_-_box-shadow);
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: var(--cr-card-border-radius);
        flex: 1;
}
```

The `--cr-card-elevation_-_box-shadow` custom property is defined as follows:

```css
--cr-card-elevation_-_box-shadow:  rgba(60, 64, 67, .3) 0 1px 2px 0,
              rgba(60, 64, 67, .15) 0 1px 3px 1px;
```